# Concatenation of pandas DataFrames including rows' source-dataframe/-category

Tags: python, pandas

I need to `pandas.concatenate(...,axis=0,...)` multiple DataFrames so that the resulting DataFrame has a new column holding information about which dataset a row belongs to, but drop the implicit indices of the original DataFrames.

In this MWE for example, we have from multiple countries (A and B, e.g.) the heights and weights of people in DataFrames `df1` and `df2`, respectively.

```
import pandas as pd

df1 = pd.DataFrame({'Weight': [5, 4, 6], 'Height': [170, 172, 180]})
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'Weight': [4, 4, 5], 'Height': [180, 181, 169]})
```

The concatenated DataFrame `df` needs to store the country for each row, but

```
df = pd.concat([df1, df2], keys=list('AB'), names=["Country"]).reset_index()
print df

>  Nationality  level_1  Height  Weight
>0           A        0     170       5
>1           A        1     172       4
>2           A        2     180       6
>3           B        0     180       4
>4           B        1     181       4
>5           B        2     169       5
```

carries along the "old" implicit indices in an additional column (`level_1`), while

```
df = pd.concat([df1, df2], keys=list('AB'), names=["Country"], ignore_index=True).reset_index()
print df
>   Height  Weight
>0     170       5
>1     172       4
>2     180       6
>3     180       4
>4     181       4
>5     169       5
```

ignores the columns marked as index of the new DataFrame instead of the indices of the source DataFrames (which would make more sense in my opinion, at least if `keys` and `names` are provided).

I get the desired result with

```
df = pd.concat([df1, df2], keys=list(list('AB')), names=["Nationality"]).reset_index(0).reset_index(0, drop=True)
print df

>      Nationality  Height  Weight
>0           A     170       5
>1           A     172       4
>2           A     180       6
>3           B     180       4
>4           B     181       4
>5           B     169       5
```

which is a syntactic nightmare IMHO.

Hence my two questions:

1. Am I missing another way to do this properly?
2. Or is the behaviour of the `ignore_index`-flag faulty or misleading and should be subject to a bug-report?

Answer (score 0):

Using both `ignore_index` and `keys` is somewhat conflicting - the first says to toss away the index information, and the second says to use it to make a `MultiIndex`.  That said, I think pandas could give a better message (maybe just raise a `ValueError`) if you pass both, so you can make an issue.

Here's an alternative way to accomplish what you want.

```
In [2]: keys = ['A', 'B']

In [3]: dfs = [df1, df2]

In [4]: df = pd.concat([df.assign(Nationality=key) for key, df
   ...:                 in zip(keys, dfs)])

In [5]: df
Out[5]: 
   Height  Weight Nationality
0     170       5           A
1     172       4           A
2     180       6           A
0     180       4           B
1     181       4           B
2     169       5           B
```

Comment: `pd.concat([df.assign(Nationality=key) for key, df in zip(keys, dfs)], ignore_index=True)` yields the required result, indeed. Although, to me it looks like using Python-features to cover up one particular lacking operation on DataFrames, although that's an ideological opinion. There is however, also a practical limitation to that solution: it will use 3 times the memory taken up by the partial frames, instead of 2 times without the copy from `.assign()`. And doing `.assign()` in-place forces us to replace the nice-looking list-comprehension with an ugly loop `df["Nationality"] = key`.

Comment: I get what you're saying, but in general trying to avoid copies while using pandas is an anti-pattern and hard to do (and copying is pretty fast!).  For example I think `df[..] = key` may (depending on df's composition) involve a copy too.  In practice, I think it's far easier to not worry about it until you actually do run into memory problems and only then optimize (or use something like `dask`)

Comment: > I think `df[..] = key` may [...] involve a copy too --  
AFAIK each column is held as an independent array and adding and removing shouldn't copy the others. But considering your pandas-score on SO, you've come across cases where this is not true or you have dug into pandas' source?! ;     
> [...] it's far easier to not worry about it until you actually do run into memory problems [...]  --  
I fully agree. I wouldn't worry if it hadn't happened so far. :/